# What is a __cf_bm cookie?

Tags: api, rest, authentication

First off, I apologize if I use any incorrect terminology. I'm familiar with calling internal apis, but this a side project and new territory for me.

I've been using chrome debugger and powershell to write some scripts against the api of a public site. I was able to retrieve the JWT token, however after a few minutes my calls will start to fail with a 403 error. To get around this I've been exporting all the request headers from chrome and storing those locally for my script to pass whenever my call to the api fails. I narrowed it down to 4 headers that must be present, the one that is most suspect seems to be "cookie".

I then removed all key value pairs in the cookie header until I found the one that makes it fail. It's named "__cf_bm". A quick google says it's some kind of cloudflare bot management data. I don't see any of the data present in the __cf_bm cookie being sent in a response during authentication, I only see it in request headers. Is it not possible to construct this value? Does this essentially prevent me from interacting with the site's api?

Comment: Sounds like the purpose of that feature (and the cookie) is to prevent automated unauthorized scripts to access the API, and it sounds like it's doing exactly what it's intending to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does prevent you from interacting with this API. I don't think it's possible to construct this value. Nonetheless, you can intercept this cookie and use it to make requests to the API since it's valid for 30 minutes after it has been approved.